# Syntax Error near "name"

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

```
conn.Open()
'MsgBox("Established!!!")

cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT price FROM products WHERE name '" & tb_pname.Text & "'"
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

While dr.Read
    Me.tb_price.Text = Convert.ToString(dr("price"))
End While

conn.Close()
```

Comment: `WHERE name = ` missed the equal

Comment: first put '=' after name in the query.second please change the way asking questions.provide more details.

Comment: Always use sql-parameters to prevent sql injection. Also, why don't you use `cmd.ExecuteScalar` if you want to find a single record's `Price`-field? Using a `While`-loop to assign text to a single control is at least confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `=` equal sign after name

```
WHERE name = '" & tb_pname.Text & "'"
```

Comment: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

Answer (score 0):

You are running wrong query. You misses `=` sign.

Here is correct query

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT price FROM products WHERE name = '" + tb_pname.Text + "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the query to not be case-sensitive, you could make a WHERE upper(name)  = upper('YourString')

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT price FROM products WHERE upper(name) = upper('" & tb_pname.Text & "')"
```

You could also use the "like" operator, where you use "WHERE name like 'PutYourTextHere' ", so you can also use wildcards like % for any string.
As an example:
WHERE name like '%Thomson%'
would find any name that contains the string 'Thomson'.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT price FROM products WHERE name like '" & tb_pname.Text & "'"
```

Comment: The default collation is case insensitive so adding UPPER in a where predicate is potentially making this query nonSARGable for no reason.